# Hibernate Parent cascade delete unidirection Child error

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a very simple Spring Boot test

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(ParentRepository parentRepo, ChildRepository childRepo) {
        return (args) -> {
            Parent parent = new Parent("Father");
            parent = parentRepo.save(parent);
            childRepo.save(new Child("Father", "Jack"));

            for (Child child : childRepo.findAll()) {
                System.out.println(child);
            }

            parentRepo.findById(parent.getName()).ifPresent(p -> {
                System.out.println(p);
    1.          p.getChildren().clear();//update child set parent_name=null NULL not allowed for column "PARENT_NAME";
    2.          p.setChildren(null);    //A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: springtest.Parent.children
                parentRepo.save(p);
            });

            for (Parent p : parentRepo.findAll()) {
                System.out.println(p);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Parent Entity

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_NAME")
    private Set<Child> children;

    protected Parent() {}

    public Parent(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Set<Child> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(Set<Child> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Parent[name=" + name + ", children=" + children.size() + "]";
    }

}
```

Child Entity

```
@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "PARENT_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String parentName;

    protected Child() {}

    public Child(String parentName, String name) {
        this.parentName = parentName;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Child[parentName=" + parentName + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }

}
```

ParentRepository

```
public interface ParentRepository extends CrudRepository<Parent, String> {}
```

ChildRepository

```
public interface ChildRepository extends CrudRepository<Child, String> {}
```

I want to remove the children from the parent entity. The link is using unidirection and the owning entity is the parent. I tried to call 1. `getChildren().clear()`, but hibernate ended up generating an update statement that sets parent_name to null (instead of a delete where parent_name="Father"), which violates the non-nullable constraint in the Child table.

Then I tried to call 2. `setChildren(null)`, this time it gave an exception `A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance`.

How do you fix the above to get the child removal working?

Answer (score 1):

As the owning entitiy the "Parent" should be the only one who modifies the foraign key. So I would drop the parentName from the "Child".

So I would change it like so:

```
@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    protected Child() {}

    public Child(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Child[name=" + name + "]";
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(ParentRepository parentRepo, ChildRepository childRepo) {
        return (args) -> {
            Parent parent = new Parent("Father");
            parent.add(new Child("Jack"));
            parent = parentRepo.save(parent); //the child is saved because of the cascading


            for (Child child : childRepo.findAll()) {
                System.out.println(child);
            }

            parentRepo.findById(parent.getName()).ifPresent(p -> {
                System.out.println(p);
                p.getChildren().clear();
                parentRepo.save(p); 
            });

            for (Parent p : parentRepo.findAll()) {
                System.out.println(p);
            }
        };
    }

}
```